# How can I hide one bar button item on a certain view controller and show it again?

Tags: ios, swift

Only when a specific **ViewController** is shown I want to append a **rightBarButtonItem**

```
    @IBAction func addView1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        addSubViewController(withStoryboardId: "View1", beginningAtX: sender.frame.origin.x)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        documentFilter.tintColor = .white
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(barButton)
    }
```

And when another **ViewController** is shown I want to remove it again:

```
 @IBAction func addView2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        addSubViewController(withStoryboardId: "View2", beginningAtX: sender.frame.origin.x)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.remove(at: 2)
    }
```

This removes the **barButtonItem**, however when I select it again it crashes cause there is no button at index 2 anymore. I made something familiar with my **tabBarItems** where I check the amount of items:

```
if (self.toolbarItems?.count ?? 0) > 0 {
            toolbarItems?.remove(at: 0)
        }
```

How would I achieve this?

---

I already tried to implement **viewWillAppear()** in my **View2** but the button is not added to the array of **rightBarButtonItems**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let barBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(barBtn)
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but as far as I know navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems is an Array and you can check its count and if an element at index 2 exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that there is no **count** method for **navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems** because Xcode always marked it as red... but I only forgot a closing bracket somewhere else..

```
if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.count ?? 0) > 2 {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.remove(at: index)
        }
```

seems to solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [viewWillAppear(*:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear) and [viewWillDisappear(:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear) functions of UIViewController to show / hide navigation bar button items.

If you want to show an item only to a particular controller, in viewWillAppear of that you can make that one visible and in viewWillDisappear you can hide the same.

Comment: I already tried this approach but it is not working. No button is added when I select the view controller